# Solr Cloud on 3.6 or 4 alpha release for .net

Tags: solr, solrnet

Does Solr 3.6 supports cloud, multiple shards & load balancing? I'm referring this.. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud/

And Solr 4 recommended for production use? Where should I look into the bugs reported on Solr 4 alpha release?

And whether solrnet works with Solr 4 alpha release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solr 3.6 does not support SolrCloud.  It does have [Distributed Search](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch) which can be used to support multiple shards, load balancing etc. with some logic on the application side.

An Alpha release will never be 'recommended' for production use. Solr 4 does have some huge advantages over Solr 3.6 and it is ultimately your decision if you want to risk it. For some more info, see [this](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2012/07/03/4-0-alpha-whats-in-a-name/).

I don't think that there is a separate page to track bugs in Solr 4 Alpha, but [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR/fixforversion/12314992) lists all the issues scheduled for Solr 4 final.

Not sure about SolrNet, but I guess it should work (except for the new features which have been introduced in Solr 4).

Comment: thanks Nikhil for your answer. We're sticking with Solr 3.6 until Solr 4 final releases and mature enough.